# How to Remove Homepage Paginated pages in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I can't find anything current for this issue.  I all of a sudden have paginated URL's showing for my site.

**Example:**

```
domain.com/
domain.com/page2/
domain.com/page3/
etc.
```

I have no pagination plugin or anything.  All of the pages are just copies of my homepage. Thank you in advance.

Comment: WordPress has built-in pagination. Where are these URLs showing?

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting a static page as homepage in apparence

Comment: It is set to a static page although I just disabled my AMP plugin and all of the paginated pages went away.  Guess my issue is with "Accelerated Mobile Pages" plugin for Wordpress and not Wordpress.  Thank you for the response.